# Conditional Aggregate Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this:

```
OrderID | PhaseID | Timestamp
1       | 1       | 1/1
1       | 2       | 1/2
1       | 3       | 1/3
1       | 2       | 1/4
1       | 4       | 1/5
```

I'm trying to get a query to return the most recent timestamp for each orderphase combination without being followed by a lesser phaseid. Something like this:

```
OrderID | PhaseID | MaxTimestampWithoutBeingFollowedByLesserPhaseID
1       | 1       | 1/1
1       | 2       | 1/4
1       | 3       | NULL
1       | 4       | 1/5
```

I keep running around in circles and coming up with this problem of a conditional aggregate query.

Can anybody figure out the query or give me some pointers?

Comment: Do you mean the next ROW is a lesser phase id, or that there are no lesser phase ids with a higher timestamp?

Comment: maybe a lttile more help on the expected output.. the one row is not really enough to make sense of your question

Comment: Also are  you just being lazy in the sample data or do you actually have `1/1` as a "time stamp"?

Comment: @JNK I mean no lesser phase IDs with greater timestamp, and yes I'm being lazy in my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With a as (
Select OrderID, PhaseID, MaxTimestamp=max([Timestamp])
From orderphase op
Where not exists(select 1 from orderphase where PhaseID < op.PhaseID 
    and [Timstamp]> op.[Timestamp])
Group by OrderID, PhaseID
)
Select distinct o.Orderid, o.PhaseID, MaxTimestamp=a.MaxTimestamp
From orderphase o
Left join a on a.OrderID = o.OrderID and a.PhaseID=o.PhaseID
```

EDIT  ref a.MaxTimestamp

Comment: @JNK - To provide the null timestamps in the result, where the phase was followed by a lesser phase.

Comment: From OP it sounds like he just wants the results that match, not the others.  Also for your query, you should use `a.MaxTimeStamp` since as written your field names don't line up.

Comment: @JNK thx, a.MaxTimestamp now referenced. Also Phase 3 is followed by phase 2, but Greg indicated that with a null in his sample result for phase 3.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rank phases by time stamps for every order.
2. Join every row with its successor based on the rank.
3. Mark the rows where `PhaseID` is followed by a lesser `PhaseID`.
4. Aggregate the last result set picking max time stamps conditionally using `MAX(CASE ...)` to omit rows marked as ones being followed by lesser PhaseIDs.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
;
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY [Timestamp])
  FROM atable
),
marked AS (
  SELECT
    r1.OrderID,
    r1.PhaseID,
    r1.[Timestamp],
    IsFollowedByLesserPhaseID = CASE WHEN r2.PhaseID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  FROM ranked r1
    LEFT JOIN ranked r2 ON r1.OrderID = r2.OrderID
                       AND r1.rnk     = r2.rnk - 1
                       AND r1.PhaseID > r2.PhaseID
)
SELECT
  OrderID,
  PhaseID,
  MaxTimestampWithoutBeingFollowedByLesserPhaseID = MAX(
    CASE IsFollowedByLesserPhaseID WHEN 0 THEN [Timestamp] END
  )
FROM marked
GROUP BY
  OrderID,
  PhaseID
```